# How to download a rpm from s3 bucket and install using ansible plabook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I have a rpm file kept in my aws s3 bucket. What I need is to download the file from s3 and install that package. All of these tasks need to be done by an ansible playbook.

Using the `get_url` ansible module I can download from s3 but how do I install the package ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply use the ansible [`yum` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) and provide the full path to your rpm for the `name` parameter. You can actually do better and install the package in a single step if you provide the url directly (rather than downloading it in a separate task).

Quoting the doc for `name`:

> You can also pass a url or a local path to a rpm file (using state=present).

Sample tasks:

```
- name: Install my remote package from uri directly
  yum:
    name: https://my.server.com/path/to/package.rpm
    state: present

- name: Install my package from a file on server
  yum:
    name: /path/to/my/package.rpm
    state: present
```